# How do I split a string delimited by newline character?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The split function works just great with space as a delimiter, but i want to split with new line as the delimiter.
I've tried

`$scope.arr = $scope.cols.split('\n');`

But it doesn't do the trick.

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.arr = [];

    $scope.makeArray = function () {

        $scope.arr=$scope.cols.split('\n');
        console.log($scope.arr);

        var parent = document.getElementById("div1");
        var child = document.getElementById("inp");
        parent.removeChild(child);

    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div style="text-align:left;">
        <input ng-model="cols"  type="text" ng-change="makeArray()" />
        <div ng-repeat="x in arr track by $index">
            <input type="text" value={{x}}>
        </div>
    </div>           
</div>
```

Comment: you have an unwanted doublequotes just before the style attribute

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is the "new line" char, while `\r` is the carriage return char. Most of the times (citation needed?) you will find `\r\n` but you can split on `\r` then `trim()` the string.

Practical experience suggests to manually check form the debug console which solution is better, so try first to split by `\r` and see if it's enough.